# set jar as default program for a file

Tags: command-line, jar, file-format, default-programs

I want to open a specific file-format with my own jar file. That means: I want to double-click the test.bo2 file and that should open my java program and send the path of that file (maybe as command-line argument). Is something like that possible?

At the moment I guess a .jar file is not a program, so is there a workaround to run a java file from a .exe or something like that? Any suggestions?

And, to go a step further, how can I automatically set this on the first startup?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: What did you try till now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are talking about ".exe" I assume you are using Windows.

You can register a new extension and the corresponding program by using `ftype` and `assoc`:

Open a commandline window, and type the following:

1. Register the new extension:

   `assoc .bo2=GenaeDocument`
2. Associate the new type with a program:

   `ftype GenaeDocument=javaw.exe -jar \path\to\your\program.jar "%1"`

You will obviously need to adjust the path to your jar file. This also assumes `javaw.exe` can be found on the path. If that is not the case, just use the full path to `javaw.exe`.

After this, a doubleclick on a `.bo2` file should start your application. I assumed you are using a Swing (GUI) application, therefor the ftype is using `javaw.exe`. If your application is a console program instead, you should use `java.exe`

(Note this can be done somehow through the ConrolPanel/Explorer as well, but I find it quicker and easier using the commandline)

Comment: thank you! I'll try that. I guess I can use the System property java.home to get the path of the javaw.exe and I'm able to run a .bat file to automatically install that on first startup?

About windows: well it would be nice if the program would run on other systems, too. if you have any suggestions about linux/mac that would be nice ;)