# Open .jar file when double-clicking on .csv file on Mac

Tags: java, macos, csv, jar, default

I've created a .jar file that displays information from a .csv file in a specific, user-friendly format. However, in order to open a .csv file with the  .jar, I have to first open the .jar, then within the program select the options to open a .csv file.

Based on this question — [set jar as default program for a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788132/set-jar-as-default-program-for-a-file) — I know it is possible to set a default on Windows that automatically opens a .jar file and sends an argument to it when you double click on a certain file type.

Is it possible to do this on a Mac? If so, is there specific code I need to add to the .jar file to support this?

Comment: .jar is just a zip file...

Comment: I understand, but a computer can "execute" a jar file as long as it has java installed, so is it possible to create a shortcut/default that would make the computer launch the jar whenever I double-click on a .csv file?

Comment: sure, tell the system that .csv files are java executables. but this isn't programming, this is system configuration.